MUI Select with options from map (ReactJS)
I want SomeComponent to include a Mui Select, that has a menu-item for each option in constraint_options's keys, and if possible, have it colored in the corresponding value.
I wrote the following code (redacted irrelevant parts):
import { MenuItem, Select } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from "react";
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [selected_constraint_type, setConstraintType] = new useState('block')
  const constraint_options = new Map([['block', 'FireBrick'], ['prefer', 'SeaGreen'],
    ['reluctant', 'DarkOrange'], ['default', 'default']])
  const onConstraintSelect = (event, val) => {
    setConstraintType(val)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Select id="constraint-select" value={selected_constraint_type} onChange={onConstraintSelect}>
        <MenuItem value={selected_constraint_type} sx={{background: 'FireBrick'}}>{selected_constraint_type}</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={selected_constraint_type} sx={{background: 'SeaGreen'}}>{selected_constraint_type}</MenuItem>
        {constraint_options.forEach((val, key) => {<MenuItem value={key} sx={{background: val}}>{key}</MenuItem>})}
      </Select>
    </>
  )
}

Currently only the 2 manually added MenuItems appear. I added the for debugging), I actually want the forEach to be working. They also don't get the colors I chose. Is there another way to do so? I'd appreciate any suggession.

Your list is an array of array ..

I saw it's a valid Map initialization on mdn
